# In Set detect back (shift) tab

Tags: .net, wpf, properties

In a set in a class I don't have access to Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) or Keyboard.Modifiers
The property is String

Is there a way to detect a back/shift tab compared to a forward tab?
A shift-tab and tab each just send a plain tab to the set.
What is sent is a forward tab and the is no Unicode for a back tab (that I can find)
So I think the answer is no but asking on SO

I tried using a converter as in the converter can detect the shift key and changing the tab to something else but the problem there is the converter is called after the set

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(String), typeof(String))]
public class StringTabConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        String strValue = (String)value;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue))  return strValue;

        if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) > 0)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("shift");
            char? lastChar = null;
            lastChar = strValue.ToCharArray()[strValue.Length-1];
            if (lastChar != null && (char)lastChar == '\t')
            {
                strValue = strValue.Replace('\t','~'); //'\v'
            }
        }
        return strValue;
        // can change it here but of no value as this is after the set
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string strValue = (String)value;
        return strValue;
    }
}
```

Where this is used for an auto suggest.
A tab as the last key is for the next suggestion.
Want to use the back tab for *prior* suggestion.
Next and prior are logical in this case.
Prior is basically sort Z-A suggestion.
Not looking for a control to do this for me.
I need to detect a back tab in the set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could have saved myself 100 points
I was just using the wrong side of the converter
ConvertBack is called before set  and Convert is called after set

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(String), typeof(String))]
public class StringTabConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        String strValue = (String)value;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Empty);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Convert " + strValue);
        //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue))  return strValue;
        return strValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string strValue = (String)value;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Empty);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ConvertBack " + strValue);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue)) return strValue;

        if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) > 0)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("shift");
            char? lastChar = null;
            char[] charArray = strValue.ToCharArray();
            lastChar = charArray[charArray.Length - 1];
            if (lastChar != null && (char)lastChar == '\t')
            {
                //strValue = strValue.Replace('\t', '~'); //'\v'
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length - 1; i++) sb.Append(charArray[i]);
                sb.Append('~');
                strValue = sb.ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ConvertBack replace " + strValue);
            }
        }
        return strValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: To be honest, I think this is wrong. A converter should not know about a Keyboard state. Unit testing this is hard because it relies on a outside state. Handle user interaction in the View. Handle (just) conversions in the converters and do all other (data) manipulation in the ViewModel

Comment: :) Sure and that's fine. I understand the appeal of working code. I am just adding the extra considerations that I have when working on the software I write: design (responsibilities) and quality (automated testability)

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Not meaning to argue with you. But even on another page the converter is aware of keyboard state. This works even if the converter is on another page. If I place the converter in pure class then it is not even found when I try and reverence it from the Window. I would have the same problem with unit testing a OnKeyUp.

Comment: Don't worry these are valid questions. My main concern is testing the Converter, not the View. In general I do not test the View automated (too many dependencies and changes there) but I do want to test the converters and ViewModels.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I am not in that environment.  Truth is I have some pissy UX people that want to be data designers.  They want the control to do stuff that is not scalable at the data side (and to me not logical).  If I mess with the keydown they will claim it is their domain.

Answer (score 1):

As the 'back tab' is not available as a [character literal in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087(v=vs.71).aspx) I see only one option:

Handle the key down/up event of the control to send a special sequence (your own literal) to the string.

Do not forget to set `e.Handled` to `true` when the special keystroke is detected.

```
public class TextBoxEx : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnKeyUp(System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Tab &&
           e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift)
        {
            //save the current position
             var previousPosition = SelectionStart;

            //insert the magic value at the current position
            Text = Text.Insert(previousPosition, "@");

            //set the current position correctly because 
            Select(previousPosition+1, 0);

            //we skip the default handling
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this doesn't handle special situations such as when the user selected a couple of characters and then types <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> but you would have to define what should happen in such a case anyway and it can easily be added.

I know this is *against* MVVM and what not but this seems to be one of those times you either handle the event, write a behavior or write a custom control.

Comment: How do you change a value in the keydown event?  e.key is read only

Comment: @Blam - Do not change the Key. Change the String/Text property. By setting `e.Handled = true;` after modifying the Text property you prevent the default addition to the Text property.

Comment: @Blam - I added an example of how to create a custom text box.

Comment: I appreciate your time and the answer but as stated in question I am not looking for a control solution.  I figured it out.  But bonus points don't go to me so you will most likely get the +100 and I am good with that.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry you did not get the bounty.  That was not my intent.  I flagged it and asked them to award you the bounty.